# Semantic Text Analysis to Group Sentences

Tags: python, scikit-learn, semantic-markup, text-analysis

To analyze the text below, is there a library that can detect the relatedness of the sentences? What I want to achieve is that "1. Marketing and all the detail of the marketing requirements are grouped together, while " 2. Merchandising" and all its detailed requirements are grouped together.

For example, Is there a Python library that can return a score of how closely related the 2 sentences, so based on the score, I can group the sentences?

"1. Marketing

```
1.1.    How are affiliate programs managed with your solution? Are any clients currently using Commission Junction as an Affiliate Partner?

1.2.    How does your solution handle attribution, if at all?

1.3.    Are any of your current clients utilizing Clearsaleing?

1.4.    Does your solution offer the ability to target banners (marketing placements) on a page based upon the attributes of the products on that page?


1.6.    Can clients define independent customer segments, complete with unique content and pricing? If so, how are these customer segments defined and managed?

2. Merchandising

2.1.    What is the largest catalog size (SKUs) you currently support? For which client?

2.2.    Please explain, in detail, your merchandising business user tool. In particular, what are the capabilities, the standard configurations, and the opportunities for customization? (Please be sure to touch on user permissions, workflow, loading of data, and QA.)

2.3.    Does your solution offer a product content management tool to organize content as it is received? If so, does this tool include a workflow component? Please describe in detail.

2.4.    Do you have experience integrating with Oracle RMS and/or RPAS Retail ERP modules, particularly in the areas of pricing, merchandising, planning, and allocation? If so, please name clients for whom you currently support this type of integration, and which module(s), in particular, are supported.

2.5.    What does your solution offer with respect to manually assigned cross-sells, up-sells, and other product recommendation functionality? 

2.6.    To what extent is it possible to integrate 3rd party merchandising tools and plug-ins with your solution? Do you have any current integrations with Certona, Rich Relevance, or other similar 3rd party solutions? 

2.7.    How do 3rd party tools and plug-in integrations affect page load times? What types of contingency plans are in place for 3rd party outages?

2.8.    Please confirm that your solution can handle multiple product types that need to be displayed and handled differently, such as Hard Goods, Digital Products, Live Fish, etc. How does a client define these in your solution? Can the client easily create distinct fulfillment rules by product type?"
```

Comment: Cosine similarity is a metric of relatedness

Comment: Thank you Nathan for the pointer. I did some experiment on it following this article: http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/.
The problem I have is that the relatedness is measured by using the same bag of words in the example, while the relatedness I need isn't exactly the same words. For example, 1.1 and 1.2 use very different words, but they all talk about marketing.

Comment: you can try to use a doc2vec model for the sentences, then use cosine similarity on them